# Google Maps: How to move zoom controls?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How can I move the Google Maps zoom controls, via the API, to the opposite side of the map?

Comment: I hate to be that guy, but did you [read the manual](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/controls.html#Control_Positioning)?

Answer (score 27):

```
var myOptions = {
                zoom: 6,

                zoomControl: true,
                zoomControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
                    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
                },

                scaleControl: true,
                panControl: true,
                navigationControl: false,              
                mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
                streetViewControl: false,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(XXX,XXX)
            }

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using version 2 of the API:

```
map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl3D(), new GControlPosition(G_ANCHOR_BOTTOM_RIGHT, new GSize(10,10)));
```

Note that the GSize will position it where you want. If you want further down than give a higher value to the second parameter

Answer (score 1):

here I am using google maps api v3 because v2 is deprecated

```
    function initialize()
    {
    var mapProp = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
    zoom:7,
    panControl:false,
    zoomControl:true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT
    },
    mapTypeControl:false,
    scaleControl:false,
    streetViewControl:false,
    overviewMapControl:false,
    rotateControl:false,    
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in css:

```
.gmnoprint:nth-child(9) { left: 50%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

From documentation the following control positions are supported:

- **TOP_CENTER** indicates that the control should be placed along the top center of the map.
- **TOP_LEFT** indicates that the control should be placed along the top left of the map, with any sub-elements of the control "flowing" towards the top center.
- **TOP_RIGHT** indicates that the control should be placed along the top right of the map, with any sub-elements of the control "flowing" towards the top center.
- **LEFT_TOP** indicates that the control should be placed along the top left of the map, but below any TOP_LEFT elements.
- **RIGHT_TOP** indicates that the control should be placed along the top right of the map, but below any TOP_RIGHT elements.
- **LEFT_CENTER** indicates that the control should be placed along the left side of the map, centered between the TOP_LEFT and BOTTOM_LEFT positions.
- **RIGHT_CENTER** indicates that the control should be placed along the right side of the map, centered between the TOP_RIGHT and BOTTOM_RIGHT positions.
- **LEFT_BOTTOM** indicates that the control should be placed along the bottom left of the map, but above any BOTTOM_LEFT elements.
- **RIGHT_BOTTOM** indicates that the control should be placed along the bottom right of the map, but above any BOTTOM_RIGHT elements.
- **BOTTOM_CENTER** indicates that the control should be placed along the bottom center of the map.
- **BOTTOM_LEFT** indicates that the control should be placed along the bottom left of the map, with any sub-elements of the control "flowing" towards the bottom center.
- **BOTTOM_RIGHT** indicates that the control should be placed along the bottom right of the map, with any sub-elements of the control "flowing" towards the bottom center.

Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls

---

e.g.:

```
const options: google.maps.MapOptions = {
  // your options
  zoomControlOptions: {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
  }
};

const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), MAP_DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
```