# Moving Map Controls on Angular 2 Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angular, angular2-google-maps

I am looking for a way to use the zoomControlOptiions property available in regular google maps, like so:

```
zoomControlOptions: {
  style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
  position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
},
```

[Stackoverflow example showing code above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638034/google-maps-how-to-move-zoom-controls)
[Same thing in the official google maps docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-positioning)

Unfortunately, I don't see this option in Angular 2 Google Maps [API Docs](https://angular-maps.com/docs/api/latest/ts/core/index/SebmGoogleMap-directive.html). Is there a way to do it? Is there a way to use the full functionality despite using the Angular 2 wrapper?

[image]

Note that just running this code works fine:

```
    map.setOptions({
      zoom: 1,
      center: position,
      zoomControl: true
    });

    console.log(map.getZoom());
```

I am able to get the native google maps object and run methods / set properties on it. The problem occurs when I try to use `zoomControlOptions`, which is coming directly from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-positioning)

---

Edit: So, it actually works, the problem now is getting around the Typescript compiler complaining.

Edit 2: I fixed the issue, but if anyone wants the bounty - feel free to explain why `zoomControlOptions` aren't natively available.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a reference to the native map object and then add the zoomControlOptions. A full example of getting the map reference is found at https://github.com/philipbrack/example-angular2-google-maps-getNativeMap:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

import {GoogleMapsAPIWrapper} from 'angular2-google-maps/core';

declare var google:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map-content',
  template: ''
})
export class MapContentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public mapApiWrapper:GoogleMapsAPIWrapper) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.mapApiWrapper.getNativeMap()
      .then((map)=> {

        // I have been manually updating core/services/google-maps-types.d.ts to include things they didn't include.
        console.log(map.getZoom());

        let position = new google.maps.LatLng(45.521, -122.677);

        var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          fillColor: '#FF0000',
          fillOpacity: 0.35,
          map: map,
          center: position,
          radius: 10000
        });


      });

  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, trying it now.

Answer (score 1):

So, apparently all I needed to do was make sure the compiler doesn't complain by creating an interface:

```
interface NativeGoogMapProps {
    zoomControlOptions?: any;
    streetViewControlOptions?: any;
}
```

and then using it when setting map options:

```
    let zoomControlOptions: any = {
      style: google.maps.ControlPosition.small,
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
    };

    let streetViewControlOptions: any =  {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
    };

    map.setOptions(<NativeGoogMapProps>{
      zoomControlOptions: zoomControlOptions,
      streetViewControlOptions: streetViewControlOptions
    });
```

I don't actually know why some props are on the map object and some are not though, but this works without errors.